# Arabic characters in URL while sharing on Twitter

Tags: php, twitter, utf-8, urlencode, arabic

I'm facing an issue trying to sharing an URL which includes arabic characters on Twitter:

```
http://example.com/قرعة-تصفيات-أفريقيا-مصر-تواجه-نيجيريا/
```

When i click on "share" the same URL is showed in the tweet box, but when I actually tweet, it just links to `http://example.com`, and the rest of the URL is lost.

I tried using `urlencode()`, but the generated URL is too long and impossible tweet. How could I solve this?

Comment: Can you use http://bit.ly , http://goo.gl , http://tinyurl.com or another URL shortener?  Most of them have APIs so you can programmatically create shorter URLs.  Also, this doesn't seem to be programming-related.  You mention php, but give no code or description of your web app other than a reference to `urlencode()`

Comment: Once check the language settings... Am not sure about it, but just check once..

Comment: Technically the URL cannot contain non-ASCII characters, you really should be URL-encoding the path there. I wouldn't be surprised if Twitter only worked with currently encoded URLs. Browsers are typically the lax ones which sometimes accept incorrect URLs as well.

Comment: Are you the owner of this website to be shared? if yes, you should rewrite the urls to be shorter, or use an id for articles instead of the full title. If you are not,  then you should shorten it by an url shortner.  I think twitter has its own dedicated shortner because I just tried sharing it and it works.

Comment: Are you trying to select and copy/paste the URL into a tweet? Arabic is read right to left, so selecting the whole URL left to right (if you're not careful) will leave out some of the URL. Try it in your address bar [here](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%B1%D8%B6), on the Arabic Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

If you are owner of website, you can write htaccess `RewriteRule` for generate shorter or English url or use Redirection file.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^redirect/(.*)/?$ ./redirector.php?key=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

And if you are user of website just you can use URL shorter websites like [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) or [goo.gl](http://goo.gl)

Comment: i used goo.gl for the shortern URLs

Answer (score 0):

You can use **RewriteRule** on **.htaccess** file or use **URL shorter** service instead

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with two sides: **Network** and **Presentation**.

## Network

URLs are never passed with other than ASCII characters. For example when you place a request for

```
http://example.com/عربي
```

It will generate an **error** or, **depending on your client e.g. Chrome**, will be **converted** to:

```
http://example.com/%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A
```

## Presentation

Internet browsers do their best to present this on the most readable way. For example when you request the following URL:

```
http://example.com/%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A
```

Chrome will present it to the user as:

```
http://example.com/عربي
```

What Chrome also does is take care of copy and paste. So when you copy an URL in the top bar and it has Unicode characters, it will copy `http://example.com/%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A` not `http://example.com/عربي`. Now what you need to do is check how twitter deals with this. It might already do some presentation to ease user experience. However, on the network side, you cant do much really.

Answer (score -1):

I use URL-shortening websites e.g. *goo.gl*; however it is more time consuming then posting a plain URL.