# Twitter Share Button for non English

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

Hey guys in first place I would thank all of you for reading my question and for  your time.
I have a "Twitter Share" button,

This is the html code:

```
<a id="TwitterShare"  target="_blank"   runat="server" rel="nofollow" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter "  aria-hidden="true">غرد</i></a>
```

And this is the code behind:

```
string RequestTwitter = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=";
string WebsiteURl = "https://www.MyWebsite.com/";
string Localurl = "Post/" + Postid + "/" + PostName;
string FullMineURL= WebsiteURl+Server.UrlEncode(Localurl);
string TwitterFinal = RequestTwitter + FullMineURL;
TwitterShare.Attributes.Add("href", TwitterFinal);
```

The code work and get the url, but when I share the link twitter isn't reading the full link, and this is beacuse the link it's seen in this way

`اكل-الجوز-وعلاقته-وفوائده-للقلب-والامعاءhttps://Mywebsite.com/Post/3163/`

I have tried to debug the code but I've find out the code come by the right way

Comment: Which line in your code results in that output اكل-الجوز-وعلاقته-وفوائده-للقلب-والامعاءhttps://Mywebsite.com/Post/3163/

Comment: string FullMineURL= WebsiteURl+Server.UrlEncode(Localurl);

Comment: Is the TwitterShare some kind of library? Do you have the code that it uses? It looks like it does automatic translation or some kind of encoding before it outputs

Comment: can you try inserting a break point `FullMineURL` and examine output, I doubt if the foreign characters are coming from there

Comment: TwitterShare is the id of the HTML anchor which take action to retweet  it's not a library   it's shown in the HTML in the code above

Comment: I already tried to insert breakpoint but it's working fine and the code comes as it should be the problem after I'm trying to share it

Comment: when you hover over the twitter share button, you still see the foreign character is that right ?

Comment: yeah is see full URL but the problem it's comes this way اكل-الجوز-وعلاقته-وفوائده-للقلب-والامعاءhttps://Mywebsite.com/Post/3163/
it's should be that way  https://Mywebsite.com/Post/3163/اكل-الجوز-وعلاقته-وفوائده-للقلب-والامعاء

Comment: try adding this line in your formload `Form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208660/discussion-between-clint-and-darwiesh-mustafa).

Comment: you can use `bitly` to shorten the url and try it out http:/ / bit.ly/32z14Rd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I ran your code and it works fine, I don't think its a problem with
>   your code (A similar problem was also reported in this
>   [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650315/arabic-characters-in-url-while-sharing-on-twitter)

You can use *URL Shortner* to shorten *url* and use this in your tweet handle, I tried and was able to share the tweet

You can sign up [here](http://bitly.com) and generate GenericAccessToken [here](https://app.bitly.com/organization/Ok2s7O9jO8A/detail?actions=profile&actions=accessToken)

Substitute `_bitlyToken` with *GenericAccessToken* which you can generate

---

*Usage*

Ensure your *Page* is marked as *Async*.`<%@ Page Async="true" %>`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
 RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(CurrentPost); 
}
async Task CurrentPost()
{ 
...
var shortenURL =  await p.ShortenAsync(FullMineURL);
string TwitterFinal = RequestTwitter + shortenURL;
TwitterShare.Attributes.Add("href", TwitterFinal);
...
}
```

*Helper Method*

```
public async Task<string> ShortenAsync(string longUrl)
{
    //with thanks to @devfunkd - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487902/nuget-package-for-bitly-to-shorten-the-links

    var url = string.Format("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token={0}&longUrl={1}",
            _bitlyToken, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(longUrl));

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    try
    {
        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            var jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
            var statusCode = jsonResponse["status_code"].Value<int>();
            if (statusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
                return jsonResponse["data"]["url"].Value<string>();

            //else some sort of problem
            Console.WriteLine("Bitly request returned error code {0}, status text '{1}' on longUrl = {2}",
                statusCode, jsonResponse["status_txt"].Value<string>(), longUrl);
            //What to do if it goes wrong? I return the original long url
            return longUrl;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        var errorResponse = ex.Response;
        using (var responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
            var errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // log errorText
            Console.WriteLine("Bitly access threw an exception {0} on url {1}. Content = {2}", ex.Message, url, errorText);
        }
        //What to do if it goes wrong? I return the original long url
        return longUrl;
    }
}
```

Thanks to [Jon's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32777645/4686729)

Comment: I'm getting null exception in this part of the code                 var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
 I checked the short link it's fine ,isn't it work in the localhost ?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: @DarwieshMustafa [continue this discussion here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208660/discussion-between-clint-and-darwiesh-mustafa)